# BUG-Chrome switching from Frame information

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm not sure if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong. I'm doing some development work that that requires me to inspect frames on a websocket connect. I do this under developer tools and click on the websocket and then frame information. Every time I do something the sends new frames Chrome immediately changes to another headers of another request. So I keep having to click back on the websocket. It didn't used to be like this and is very frustrating. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I'm convinced this is a bug. As there has been a recent change around the prettying up the frame information...

Comment: Same thing happening to me on Ubuntu (both latest stable chrome and latest beta version)

Comment: Hi Bernard, I'm actually surprised more people haven't commented.... I raised a bug through Chrome not sure what their turn around of releases is... Thanks for confirming ;) Also i didn't realise I have automatic updates on :S

Comment: Please share a link to the bug you raised :)

Comment: Nevermind, found it: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=592911 und https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=594511

Comment: I'm getting this too. It's SUPER frustrating and annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe this is fixed as at Version 51.0.2704.103 Mac

Comment: broken in ubuntu chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)